# jenkins-operator order of seed jobs

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have configured kubernetes jenkins-operator seed jobs successfully according to https://jenkinsci.github.io/kubernetes-operator/docs/getting-started/latest/configuration/

Now I would like to create a folder structure for my jobs, for example I have this folders.groovy

```
folder('Examples') {
    displayName('Example Jobs')
    description('Folder for example jobs')
}

folder('DockerImages') {
    displayName('Docker Images')
    description('Folder for jobs baking Docker images')
}
```

The yaml refers to *.groovy in the seed job location:

```
apiVersion: jenkins.io/v1alpha2
kind: Jenkins
metadata:
  namespace: jenkins
  name: xxx
spec:
  configurationAsCode:
    configurations:
      - name: jenkins-operator-user-configuration
  master:
    plugins:
      - name: amazon-ecr
        version: "1.6"
      - name: greenballs
        version: "1.15"
    containers:
    ...

  seedJobs:
    - id: jenkins-operator-ssh
      credentialType: basicSSHUserPrivateKey
      credentialID: jenkins-github
      targets: "infra/jobs/*.groovy"
      description: "Infra DSL jobs"
      repositoryBranch: master
      repositoryUrl: git@github.com:xxx/yyyy.git
```

How can I make sure that my folders.groovy file is processed first? Is it going in alphabetic order?

Comment: did find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple folders or multiple files:

targets: infra/folders/*.groovy\ninfra/jobs/*.groovy

---

targets: infra/folders.groovy\ninfra
targets: "infra/jobs/*.groovy"